# Set Specific alerts on SVN commit with Tortoise

Tags: tortoisesvn

I noticed that in my developpment team, sometimes someone forgets to commit a file that must go with an other to keep the site working. this causes problemes and waste of time...
The question is : Is it possible to tell SVN tortoise : if someone tries to commit a file A without files (A1, A2,...An) ask them if they are sure they don't need to commit them too?

Comment: You must to add more details -it isn't so obvious, there your real problem now, because previous versions of "missed" files still exist in repo

Answer (score 2):

You need to have look at [hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks).`hook` is nothing but a program triggered by some repository event.You can write whatever set of activities(alert in your case) inside hooks.use `pre hooks` for running the hooks before any task take place.

**EDIT**:

Refer [commit monitor](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/).CommitMonitor is a small tool to monitor Apache™ Subversion® repositories for new commits.

Comment: Bad idea - hooks are non-interactive and can't "ask" - they only block or enable commit **silently**

Comment: Thank you!! I'll check how I can implement a red warning message on commit!